# How to draw live-data with time passed in milliseconds on x-axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to programing and I am currently trying to visualize force data per second. 
The Data is "given me" in realtime through a simulation.

I tried using time.time() for the x-axes, but plt.plot won't show anything with that command, only plt.scatter(), but since I want a line plot I can not just use plt.scatter.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import time

Application = Dispatch('Program I am using')
myPlatform = Application.ActiveExperiment.Platforms[0]

while (True):

        if(myPlatform.ActiveVariableDescription.Variables["Platform():]")

                soll_kraft = myPlatform.ActiveVariableDescription.Variables["Platform():]")
                ist_kraft = myPlatform.ActiveVariableDescription.Variables["Platform():]")

                ts = time.time()

                plt.scatter(ts, soll_kraft, color='red')
                plt.scatter(ts, ist_kraft, color='green')
                plt.plot(ts, soll_kraft, color='red')
                plt.plot(ts, ist_kraft, color='green')

                plt.pause(0.005)
                plt.draw()
        else:
                plt.close()
```

I expect scatter points connected via line, but instead I just get points.

Comment: First of all you have syntax errors in your code... Please give a [mcve]

Comment: You're trying to plot a line plot of a single point. That will not result in anything shown because a line needs at least two points to be a line.

Comment: Every third of a second there is a new point, is there a possibility to connect the new point with the old one before him and so on?